# Eascaping special characters from BLOB data types

Tags: java, oracle, text, blob, special-characters

I am reading a BLOB data type tables from Oracle database. But the special characters are escaping from that. below is my code.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException

{

    System.out.println("Oracle Connect START.");
    Connection conn = null;

    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:";
    String dbName = "xe";
    String driver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
    String userName = "T24DBA";
    String password = "ABCD123abcd";
    int locationofp=0;
    ResultSet orset = null;
    ResultSet rs1 = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        orset =stmt.executeQuery("select RECID, XMLRECORD from karthi");

        Blob lob = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/DataRead/fbnk.txt");
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

        while (orset.next()) {
            String RECID = orset.getString(1);


            lob=orset.getBlob("XMLRECORD");
            byte[] bdata = lob.getBytes(1, (int) lob.length());
            String text = new String(bdata);
            System.out.println("TEXT "+ text);
        }
    }
```

The record in the Database is

```
EUR100011510þGBP100011200þGBP100011250þGBP100011500þGB
```

But the output i got is

```
EUR100011510�GBP100011200�GBP100011250�GBP100011500�GB
```

All my field Marker characters(þ) are escaping.

Any help will be much appreciated. I am struggling this for the past two days

Thanks

Comment: OP, is this [tag:Java]? I added the java tag, but if it isn't, my apology.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your Default charset is not UTF-8 and the bytes for your special char are -61 -66 (Not ascii)

Try

```
System.out.println(new String (bdata, "UTF-8"));
```

Example

```
    byte[] str = "EUR100011510þGBP100011200þGBP100011250þGBP100011500þGB".getBytes();

    try {
        System.out.println(new String (str, "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, After adding UTF-8 also i am not getting. All the special characters are escaping.

Comment: Can you confirm that your bytes are correct.  As I said the special char is -61 -66.  If the data is not correct originally, we need to look at that.

Comment: Hi, i have checked the bytes are correct only. i dont know why my special characters are escaping

Comment: Hi, i have tried your above sample but getting as "EUR100011510?GBP100011200?GBP100011250?GBP100011500?GB"

Comment: Something strange with your setup I think.  What IDE are you using?

Comment: Hi, After adding the JVM Parameter to -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 i am getting as "EUR100011510Ã¾GBP100011200Ã¾GBP100011250Ã¾GBP100011500Ã¾GB"

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE & the version is Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911

Comment: yes, but i have added default character set to UTF-8 only. What is the possibility to get as UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that data stored into your database is in UTF-8 format.
Also create a new String with specifying encoding:

```
String text = new String(bdata, "UTF-8");
System.out.println("TEXT "+ text);
```

Comment: Hi Yury, Thanks for your quick response!  After creating a new string with specific encoding also my special characters are escaping. Any idea behind this..

Comment: It is strange that the example from @user2310289 comment does not work.
Just another guess - try to add JVM parameter -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

Comment: After Adding the JVM parameter i am getting as "EUR100011510Ã¾GBP100011200Ã¾GBP100011250Ã¾GBP100011500Ã¾GB"

Comment: But i have added default character set to "UTF-8"

Comment: Try another guess:
Go into Window->Preferences in Eclipse and setup Text file encoding in General->Workspace to UTF-8. After that recreate a file with the simple test from @user2310289.